# powershell: Find all mailboxes on Server Foo whose owners are in AD group Bar

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, powershell

I am unsuccessful at attempting the following - maybe I have not correctly grasped the connection between AD users and Exchange mailboxes, also I often fail at seeing the simple ways for manipulation in powershell:

I have several Exchange servers in my domain and need all mailboxes that are on a given server ("Foo") where the owning AD user is a member of AD group "Bar"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ADGroupMember "groupName" | ForEach-Object {
    get-mailbox $_.distinguishedname |
        where-object {$_.servername -eq 'serverName'}
}
```

Replace groupName and serverName as appropriate.

Comment: You might also want `-recursive` after "groupName", if you nest groups within groups.